# Set constant for reusing HTML

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, html

I am trying to set a WWW_ROOT in order to reuse HTML code in different pages. This is an example of users.php using a header, where the CSS files are not found - 404 (Not Found) and I got `Notice: Undefined variable: project_end in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/lpweb/assets/php/initialize.php on line 11`

**Folder structure**

```
>localhost
  >lpweb
       >index.php
       >pages
          >users.php
       >assets
          >php
             >initialize.php
             >header.php
          >css
             >bootstrap.min.css
```

**initialize.php**

```
<?php
  define("PHP_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));
  define("ASSETS_PATH", dirname(PHP_PATH));

  $public_end = strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/lpweb') + 7;
  $doc_root = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, $project_end); //line 11
  define("WWW_ROOT", $doc_root);
?>
```

**header.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="<?php echo WWW_ROOT . 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'; ?>"> />
```

**users.php**

```
<?php require_once('../assets/php/initialize.php'); ?>
<?php include(PHP_PATH . '/header.php'); ?>
```

Comment: How is it not working? Does it give an error (like `WWW_ROOT does not exist`)? Does `WWW_ROOT` contain the wrong path? What is the actual `href` value of the stylesheet and what do you expect it to be?

Comment: make sure that error reporting is enabled. Once verified, tell us if you have any errors thrown back and/or something in your logs. You didn't include error handling in what you posted. Check what your HTML source reveals also.

Comment: what does this have to do with javascript and node.js? there's no code for those tags used.

Comment: @rickdenhaan The CSS is not found because WWW_ROOT redirect to localhost instead of lpweb: `GET http://localhost/css/bootstrap.min.css 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Because I thought probably there is other simple ways using node.js than PHP.

Comment: You are mixing $public_end and $project_end

Comment: @RinsadAhmed And that's it. Thanks very much for your patience and help. Really appreciated!

Comment: @AntonioAndrés why don't you help me giving a vote and accepting the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing $public_end and $project_end

Also after reviewing your code from GitHub I believe this will work for you.

```
define("WWW_ROOT",$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/'));
```

Alternatively, you can use the relative path to refer to CSS files which will make your life easy

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Comment: Thanks Rinsad. I don't want to the relative paths since I have several folders and   subfolders, so it would be a headache to include the relative paths everywhere. I have edited the question with more details.

Comment: Did you try this final step as I have given? define("WWW_ROOT",rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),'',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),'/')); Whats the issue you have?

Comment: Ok, that helped. I have edited the answer. Please use that

Comment: @AntonioAndrés why don't you help me giving a vote and accepting the answer?

Comment: Hi Rinsad, the correct answer is "You are mixing $public_end and $project_end". Please, add it as an answer I will do it straight away!